# SQL count result always out by 1

Tags: php, sql, count

I am trying to count out the number of SQL entries that match todays date, I have this snippet....

```
$todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");
$count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM my_table WHERE date_created LIKE '%$todaysdate%'" );
echo $count[0]->count;
```

I am using **LIKE** instead of **=** as they date_created also includes the time like so....

```
2014-01-27 03:30:17
```

For some reason this always reports the correct number but +1

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are your input data and expected output?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why use `LIKE` and not `=` sign?

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are selecting only 1 object. `$count[0]`

try this:

```
$todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");
$count = num_rows("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM my_table WHERE date_created LIKE '%$todaysdate%'" );
echo $count;
```

Comment: That just gives me the number 1

Comment: What should the result have been?

Comment: The result in this instance should have been 2567

Comment: I just changed my answer, try new 1 using num_rows